# Proving that the zero vector is unique

Tags: linear-algebra

We are supposed to prove that the zero vector is unique with the additive identity $x+O=x$ and then by creating another additive identity with $O'$, then $x+O'=x$.

We set them equal $x+O=x+O'$ and use the vector cancelling theorem to get $O=O'$, but how does this prove that the zero vector is unique?

Answer (score 5):

Well, you proved that two "zeroes" are actually the same, so you only have one. A cleaner proof is $$0 \stackrel{(1)}{=} 0+0' \stackrel{(2)}{=} 0',$$where in (1) use use that $0'$ is neutral for $+$ (on the right), and in (2) use that $0$ is neutral for $+$ (on the left).

Answer (score 2):

Let (V, +, ·) be a vector space over ℝ. 
According to the definition of zero vector,
*u* + 0 = 0 + *u* = *u*, ∀ *u* ∈ V
on the contrary, let 0' be another zero vector and 0'∈V such that 
*u* + 0' = 0' + *u* = *u*, ∀ *u* ∈ V

Consider 0+0' 
since 0 is zero vector of V, 
*u* + 0 = 0 + *u* = *u*, ∀ *u* ∈ V
taking *u* = 0', 
0+0' = 0'  (i)

0' is also a zero vector of V according to our assumption. 
Therefore ∀ *u* ∈ V, 
*u* + 0' = 0' + *u* = *u*
taking *u* = 0,
0+0' = 0  (ii)

from (i) and (ii), 
0' = 0 as required

Comment: This adds nothing new to the already existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

If there are two distinct additive identities, $O$ and $O'$, then by your steps we have $O=O'$, contradiction.