# Comparison of some of the different ways to prove the uniqueness of the zero vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let me preface by saying that I am attempting to teach myself some math despite having very little background in it. So, I apologize if my question seems trivial:

For proving the uniqueness of the zero vector, of the two proofs below, why is the first one generally considered "cleaner" or "better"?

Proof 1:

Suppose 0 and 0' are zero vectors. Then,

$0=0+0'$ (given 0' is the zero vector)

$\implies 0=0'+0$ (by commutativity)

$\implies 0=0'$ (given $0$ is a zero vector)

Thus, the zero vector is unique.//

Proof 2:

Suppose $0$ and $0'$ are zero vectors. Then, for any element x, $x+0=x$ and $x+0'=x$. Then,

$x+0=x+0'$

$\implies -x+x+0=-x+x+0'$

$\implies 0=0'$ (by additive inverse)

Hence, the zero vector is unique.

I know there are other similar versions like here [Proving that the zero vector is unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458123/proving-that-the-zero-vector-is-unique)
but I am rather new to proof writing and want to figure out why something is considered a "better" proof than others.

Thanks!

Comment: The first proof would generally be considered "better" since it involves fewer steps, and avoids introducing the unnecessary variable $x$.

Comment: They are both correct and succinct. One thing to notice here is that you do not use the whole vector space structure. Just the fact that it is a group under addition. The identity in a group is unique as either of your proofs shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second proof, you proved that for all vectors $x$, $0=0’$. When you conclude then that $0=0’$, you’re assuming that there is a vector. This is of course true (the zero vector always exists), but it’s more straightforward to just have used the zero vector explicitly from the start.

The first proof is also better because it works for arbitrary monoids, even when there are no inverses.

Also if you’re assuming $-x+x=0$ (and not $0’$), the step you skipped before the last step is $0+0=0+0’$, which is no better than just starting with an equation like that.

The first proof can also be written as just the single string of equations $0=0+0’=0’$, which makes it especially clean.